# Cordova error CompileDebug VersionCodes

Tags: java, android, cordova

I try to run an app on an Android 4.3 device, but the problem is when phonegap wants the Android-22 to run. I go and change the target from 22 to 18 in the Manifest and `project.properties` (CordovaLib same) but I got an error on `:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava` trying to find the `VersionCodes`, only focus in KitKat or Lollipop.

```
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\JorgeMatías\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat"""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device 'YT910FX45P'.
Running: C:\Users\JorgeMatías\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\JorgeMatías\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^
  symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: package android.webkit
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    private final ClientCertRequest request;
                  ^
  symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: class CordovaClientCertRequest
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    public CordovaClientCertRequest(ClientCertRequest request) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: class CordovaClientCertRequest
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:251: error: cannot find symbol
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                                                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   class FileChooserParams
  location: class WebChromeClient
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^
  symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: package android.webkit
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onReceivedClientCertRequest (WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: class SystemWebViewClient
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:249: error: cannot find symbol
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable LOLLIPOP
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewEngine.java:218: error: cannot find symbol
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable KITKAT
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable LOLLIPOP
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
                         ^
  symbol:   method setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(WebView,boolean)
  location: variable cookieManager of type CookieManager
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable LOLLIPOP
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
            cookieManager.flush();
                         ^
  symbol:   method flush()
  location: variable cookieManager of type CookieManager
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:257: error: cannot find symbol
                    Uri[] result = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable FileChooserParams
  location: class WebChromeClient
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:250: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewEngine.java:182: error: cannot find symbol
            android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable KITKAT
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewEngine.java:221: error: cannot find symbol
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                   ^
  symbol:   method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)
  location: class WebView
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:114: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\JorgeMatÝas\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:352: error: cannot find symbol
        return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && "content".equals(uri.getScheme());
                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable KITKAT
  location: class VERSION_CODES
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
18 errors
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.918 secs

C:\Users\JorgeMat├¡as\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c ""C:\Users\JorgeMat├¡as\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\JorgeMat├¡as\Desktop\mobile app\mobile\platforms\android\build.gradle" -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```